# regular expression part of URL extract

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

need a little help with extracting part of the URL via regex

I have URL which looks like this:

```
http://www.something.com/offer/1/all-[part to be extracted]-offers-discounts
```

First parameter is static/fixed (`/offer/`), second one is number variable (`/1/`) which is in range of x-xxxxx.

This needs to be 301 redirected to: `http://www.something.com/[part to be extracted]`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http://www.something.com/offer/\d+/all-(.*)-offers-discounts
```

redirect to

```
http://www.something.com/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the Incoming url on "/" if using Java use **string.split()** take the last index of the returned array in a variable say **resultSplit**, again split **resultSplit** on "-" take the second index from the result array and use it for redirection on the new url.